# How to write Bray-Curtis function?

Tags: r, geospatial, distance, vegan, economics

i tried to write braycurtis function on my own. My data is economic,social data about different regions(each row is diffrent region and each column is economenter image description hereic index). Sample(data is already normalized in range 0-1, thats why best region, the standard region have value 1)- real data have more regions and values :P

```
Region= c("A", "B", "C")
Sp1 =c(0.43, 1, 0.5)
Sp2 = c(0.53, 0.12, 0.75)
...
Sp23 = c(0.97, 0.2, 1)
Sp24 = c(0.34, 0.72, 0.23)
```

I need synthetic index of development, thats why i try to use bray_curtis. That's code of my function

```
bray_curtis <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  return(1-(rowSums(abs(x - max(x))))/rowSums(x+max(x)))
}
gus2016_braycurtis <- as.data.frame(lapply(gus2016_norm, bray_curtis))
```

Formula, that i tried to implement
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRrBb.png

What should i change? to output i need **one** colum of synthetic index of development for each region.

Comment: Provide some reproducible data and show your desired results. Functions `vegdist` in package `vegan` and `bcdist` in  package `ecodist` compute the Bray-Curtis index.

Comment: BC (dis)similarity index compares *two* vectors element by element. It tells how (dis)similar these two are. It does *not* give any synthetic index of development for *one* vector. If you take a column of BC (dis)similarities, that only tells how (dis)similar each column is to that column. Do you really want to use BC (dis)similarities? Or are you looking for something completely different? Such as some "synthetic index of development"?

Comment: I wrote a longish answer to your original question, but I think that you really do not want to use pairwise Bray-Curtis (dis)similarity and I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I think you do not want to have Bray-Curtis index, I show how to get it. Your math needs fixing: your calculations had little to do with the formula you [linked to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRrBb.png) (and even that linked formula botches indices, but let's ignore that and implement the formula that was intended).

BC index is a dissimilarity or similarity index calculated between two rows (or columns). When calculated just for one observation (that is, when indices are equal and the row/column is just duplicated) it will be 0 (if distance) or 1 (if similarity). The linked formula defines a similarity index. Here is a straightforward implementation of the linked formula for matrix `z` and doing calculations between rows. You need to switch indexing if you want to calculate similarities between columns:

```
N <- nrow(z) # assuming that matrix/data.frame z exists
d <- matrix(0, N, N)
for(i in 1:N) for(j in 1:N) d[i,j] <- 1 - sum(abs(z[i,]-z[j,]))/sum(z[i,]+z[j,])
## d[i,j] <- 2*sum(pmin(z[i,], z[j,]))/sum(z[i,]+z[j,]) is mathematically equivalent
```

This will give you a symmetric matrix with diagonal of 1 (so a lot of redundant work was done).

Then there is an easy way, as the BC index has been implemented in several packages. I just show how to get it in **vegan**, where we need to change the dissimilarity to similarity, and I also cast the distance structure to symmetric matrix as above:

```
library(vegan)
d <- 1 - as.matrix(vegdist(z)) # assuming that z exists
```

Probably you don't want to have this, but here you see how to get it.